# Why saving a bitmap in external storage failed, even though bitmap is created properly and can be displayed in imageView?

Tags: android, share, screenshot, android-external-storage

I can successfully run intent sharing a cap screen (bitmap) from a file location "file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg". But now i am stuck at saving the bitmap to that location.

I included the following in manifests

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Also this function to check permission:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // do your stuff
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(iv_ScoreBoard.this, "GET_ACCOUNTS Denied",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions,
                    grantResults);
    }
}
```

Onclick Sharing button:

```
    View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    Bitmap bitmaptest = getScreenShot(rootView);

    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "@Share from App \"XXYY\"");
    share.setType("image/jpeg");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmaptest.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));

            return true;
```

getScreenShot(View view)

```
public static Bitmap getScreenShot(View view) {
    View screenView = view.getRootView();
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
    screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return bitmap;
}
```

It produces a black screen cap as a picture when share button is clicked...
No file is created, no error is found.

Comment: Did you look to see if the file was created in that folder? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @HB. No file is created, no error is found....

Comment: When sharing a file with a Uri you need to provide Uri permissions.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/grant-uri-permission-element

Comment: @HB. Yes the bitmap is created, I can even assign to some ImageView and it works just fine. Uri permission! I didn't think of that, thanks for reminding, let me try tomorrow!

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.

Comment: @HB. I have included "android:grantUriPermissions="true" " in my <activity> in manifest, still a black image after pressing "share button". Am I missing on something?

Comment: You should also add `share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);` underneath `share.setType("image/jpeg");`

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not requesting/checking permissions at least in the code provided by you in the question.

Your code only implements onRequestPermissionResult, which is called to notify you the results once you have requested the permissions.

You must request permission.

Implement following in your activity.

```
 final int requestCode1 = 100;//this is the constant which you pass while requesting permission.
 // this code helps you to identify which permission was requested in onPermissionResultReceived, in case you are dealing with more than one permission groups. 
 ....
 onCreate(){
 ... // your code goes here
 ...
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view){
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, 
     Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // Permission is not granted
    // request permission    
     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(iv_ScoreBoard.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, requestCode1);
 } else{
    //permission granted
    takeScreenShot();
 }
```

**Your onRequestPermissionsResult**

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
switch (requestCode) {
    case requestCode1:
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // do your stuff
             takeScreenShot();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(iv_ScoreBoard.this, "Permission Denied",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;
    default:
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions,
                grantResults);
   }
}
```

Add above code in onCreate or just before performing the action that requires these permission.

Refer - https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java

Comment: may I know where should I include this code? is it inside my "onRequestPermissionsResult()"? When I try to include it in oncreate(), the "requestCode" is "unable to resolve symbol", so I guess it is inside "onRequestPermissionsResult()"? Please forgive my ignorance, thanks!

Comment: requestCode is an integer that you have to set. I am updating the answer to clarify

Comment: Hope you got the point. Please accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: This is the way I used in my apps  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mayank.bhaktirasamritaswami. And  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mayank.srilaprabhupadavani

Comment: The application would crash if no runtime permission was provided. Instead it doesn't crash and the file is still created.

Comment: Hey. No need to apologize. You are just presenting your views.

Comment: By the way I often commit much bigger mistakes, but then we try to improve also.

Answer (score 1):

When sharing a file to another application you need to provide `Uri` permissions.

To do that you first have to create a provider in your `Manifest`, like this:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

`@xml/provider_paths` will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="SavedImages" path="Android/data/com.yourpackagename.yourappname/files/SavedImages/"/>
</paths>
```

You will have to create the above in your `res`->`xml` folder I called mine `provider_paths.xml`

If you do not have a xml folder, create one.

---

then when you share your file you should provide the permissions:

```
Uri imageUri;
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    imageUri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg");
}else {
    File newFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
    imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", newFile);
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
}
share.setType("image/jpeg");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
share(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share image using"));
```

---

**I honestly do not think your issue is regarding runtime permissions.** If it was you would get a crash and the file would not be created. As you stated in your question `It produces a black screen cap as a picture when share button is clicked... No file is created, no error is found.`.

When not providing `Uri` permissions, other other hand, will most likely produce a Uri exposed exception.

The file will still be created, but it would be empty. Like you are experiencing.

Comment: No. The app does not crash because the read-write to file is done inside try-catch block

Comment: The creating of bitmap does not require permission as he is taking screenshot of his own app and not reading or writing anything.

Comment: @m__ from the question - `It produces a black screen cap as a picture when share button is clicked... No file is created, no error is found.` No need to dislike!

Comment: File is not created because the try block fails